# What controls the Encryption of password in DaoAuthenticationProvider?

Tags: spring-security

I am receiving a org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException when I'm trying to log into my web app.

In my configuration xml

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider ref="authProvider"/>
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="authProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
    <beans:property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="strength" value="11" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="userDetailsService"
    class="com.kable.web.hub.service.impl.UserDetailsServiceImpl" />
```

You can see the passwordEncoder is provided to authProvider. I have verified the encrypted password is stored in the database and retrieved by the UserDetailsServiceImpl in the following.

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    logger.debug(String.format("loadUserByUsername %s", userName));
    User user = userService.get(userName);
    if (user == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No user found with username: " + userName);
    }
    boolean enabled = true;
    boolean accountNonExpired = true;
    boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
    boolean accountNonLocked = true;
    
    logger.debug(String.format("loadUserByUsername password %s", user.getPassword()));
    
    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
      user.getName(), user.getPassword().toLowerCase(), enabled, accountNonExpired,
      credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, getAuthorities(userService.listRolesForUserName(userName)));
}
```

Comment: Since you're directly using BCryptPasswordEncoder, make sure the passwords in the database do not start with "{bcrypt}". If they do, you will want to use [DelegatingPasswordEncoder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.5.x/reference/html5/#authentication-password-storage-dpe) instead.

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg They do not. Here is a line from the log that I dumped out in the UserDetailsServiceImpl `15:11:37 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-19]:service.impl.UserDetailsServiceImpl.loadUserByUsername()39 - loadUserByUsername password $2a$11$UtXCuGuCDO7YAWQDJDLA/eusiU/xpD1g2gBDVv3St/pXuQB427Ajy
`.

Comment: Try removing `.toLowerCase()`.

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg - Brilliant, thanks! I don't know how that got in there.